# Why can't Kotlin infer the type in this example?

Tags: kotlin, generics

In the following example the compiler figures out that because of the object identity check of `b1.a` to `b2.a` that they must have the same type. However, it can't seem to figure out that because of `b1.a` having type `A<T2>` `b1.t` must have type `T2`.

```kotlin
class A<T>
class B<T>(val t: T, val a: A<T>)
fun <T1, T2> foo(b1: B<T1>, b2: B<T2>) {
    if (b1.a !== b2.a) return
    val otherA: A<T2> = b1.a // smart cast
    val otherT: T2 = b1.t // type mismatch error
    b1.a as A<T2> // useless cast
    b1 as B<T2> // unchecked cast warning
}
```

Comment: Too many steps of logic to determine. It simply isn't that sophisticated.

Comment: As far as I am concerned, just because both `b1.a` and `b2.a` are equal does not mean that `T1` and `T2` are equal types. Yes, either `T1` or `T2` is a subtype of the other, but I don't think the inference engine is capable of realizing this.

Comment: @supergrecko if b1.a and b2.a are the same instance (it's doing a identity check, not equals), their type argument needs to be the same, which Kotlin recognizes. But then the type argument of B should also be the same